# getlocale() function in C

Tags: c

I can set a locale using the `setlocale()` function. But is there any way I can get the locale and save it in a variable so that I can reset it later.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
str=getlocale(LC_CTYPE);
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"en_US");
...
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,str);
```

How can I implement the `getlocale()` function, or is there any alternative?

Comment: this localeconv: returns a local structure I believe

Comment: You can read [HERE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) about setlocale(3). or use `man setlocale` if you are on an Unix machine.

Comment: Did you even **try** reading the man page? (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html)  *The setlocale() function is used to set or query the program's current locale.  ...  A successful call to setlocale() returns an opaque string that corresponds to the locale set.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass `NULL` and use the return value. See [`setlocale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale)

> You can also use this function to find out the current locale by passing a null pointer as the locale argument. In this case, setlocale returns a string that is the name of the locale currently selected for category category.

Or in the C standard:

> **7.11.1.1 The setlocale function**
> ....
>
> If a pointer to a string is given for `locale` and the selection can be honored, the
>   `setlocale` function returns a pointer to the string associated with the specified
>   `category` for the new locale. If the selection cannot be honored, the `setlocale`
>   function returns a null pointer and the program’s locale is not changed.
>
> A null pointer for `locale` causes the `setlocale` function to return a pointer to the
>   string associated with the `category` for the program’s current locale; the program’s
>   locale is not changed.
>
> The pointer to string returned by the `setlocale` function is such that a subsequent call
>   with that string value and its associated category will restore that part of the program’s
>   locale.

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
char* getlocale( int cat )
{
    return setlocale( cat, NULL ) ;
}
```

your code will still not quite work, because the pointer returned is a reference to the current locale, *not* a copy.  You need to take a copy:

```
char saved_locale[32] ;
strcpy( saved_locale, getlocale(LC_CTYPE) ) ;
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "en_US" ) ;
...
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, saved_locale ) ;
```

or

```
char* saved_locale = strdup( getlocale(LC_CTYPE) ) ;
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "en_US" ) ;
...
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, saved_locale ) ;
free( saved_locale ) ;
```

Comment: 32 seems reasonable.  Any insight to a specified max size?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : In Windows, surprisingly 85; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-name-constants.  For Linux, the question was asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639579/what-should-be-the-size-of-buffer-to-store-the-locale-name-in-linux, but not really answered.  Instead the suggestion was to use a VLA. `strdup()` might be preferred.

Comment: Also: [85](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-name-constants) looks like the max VS _length_, so the size needed there is `char saved_locale[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH+1];`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, that is the same link I posted.  No +1 required, that value includes the null terminator. This is 6 years old, and the target was not specified. strncpy could prevent an overrun but risks truncation.

Answer (score 3):

See below example given in [GNU page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html#Setting-the-Locale), similar to your purpose:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void
with_other_locale (char *new_locale,
                   void (*subroutine) (int),
                   int argument)
{
  char *old_locale, *saved_locale;

  /* Get the name of the current locale.  */
  old_locale = setlocale (LC_ALL, NULL);

  /* Copy the name so it won't be clobbered by setlocale. */
  saved_locale = strdup (old_locale);
  if (old_locale == NULL)
    fatal ("Out of memory");

  /* Now change the locale and do some stuff with it. */
  setlocale (LC_ALL, new_locale);
  (*subroutine) (argument);

  /* Restore the original locale. */
  setlocale (LC_ALL, saved_locale);
  free (saved_locale);
}
```