# What should be the size of buffer to store the locale name in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, locale, setlocale

I want to store the locale name returned by the setlocale() function on Linux.
As in Windows platform, max locale size is defined as [LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-name-constants), Is there any similar macro defined for Linux? Also, I need to use same buffer on both the mentioned platforms.

```
char buffer[];
buffer = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
```

Comment: I’m not sure there’s a comparable equivalent. Locales in Linux can consist of concatenations of path names identifying individual locale files (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html), which suggests there’s no fixed upper bound.

Comment: Why is the pointer itself not enough, i.e. why copy it into your program's storage?

Answer (score 5):

The procedure you suggested in your question won’t work. You cannot assign `setlocale`’s return value (type `char *`) to a local array:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [10]’
  buffer = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
                                 ^
```

You must assign the return value to a *pointer*, then you can examine its actual length using `strlen` and copy it to your array using `strcpy`:

```
#include <locale.h>  // setlocale
#include <string.h>  // strlen, strcpy
#include <stdio.h>   // printf

int main()
{
    char* pLocale;
    pLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    char buffer[strlen(pLocale)+1];  // + 1 char for string terminator, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905963/711006
    strcpy(buffer, pLocale);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

[See it online.](https://ideone.com/8I3TWb)

The above is actually a C-compatible code. If you’re using C++, you can use `setlocale`’s return value to directly initialize a `std::string` without managing a `char` array manually:

```
#include <locale.h>  // setlocale
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    std::cout << locale << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[See it online.](https://ideone.com/9TsYsG)

Comment: No variable length arrays, please.

Comment: @j6t I added a “pure” C++ version. Please check it now.